# Read XML Webfile in C# Windows Form and place data in labels

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

For my information program I need to read a web xml file and place it in a label for every value.

An example of the XML file:

```
<ActueleVertrekTijden>
      <VertrekkendeTrein>
        <RitNummer>5070</RitNummer>
        <VertrekTijd>2015-03-20T19:42:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
        <EindBestemming>Den Haag Centraal</EindBestemming>
        <TreinSoort>Sprinter</TreinSoort>
        <RouteTekst>Lage Zwaluwe, Dordrecht, Rotterdam C.</RouteTekst>
        <Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
        <VertrekSpoor wijziging="false">6</VertrekSpoor>
     </VertrekkendeTrein>
     <VertrekkendeTrein>
        <RitNummer>1971</RitNummer>
        <VertrekTijd>2015-03-20T19:50:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
        <EindBestemming>Venlo</EindBestemming>
        <TreinSoort>Intercity</TreinSoort>
        <RouteTekst>Tilburg, Eindhoven, Helmond</RouteTekst>
        <Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
        <VertrekSpoor wijziging="false">4</VertrekSpoor>
        <Opmerkingen> // This is not always available, but it is important and specific for a 'VertrekkendeTrein'
          <Opmerking>Rijdt vandaag niet</Opmerking>
            </Opmerkingen>
        </VertrekkendeTrein>
</ActueleVertrekTijden>
```

I tried it with XMLDocument (using foreach) like this:

```
 foreach (XmlNode nodelist2 in nodeList)
            {
                if (i < 1) //1
                {

                    switch (nodelist.Name)
                    {
                        case "VertrekTijd": string vertrek1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
                        case "VertrekVertragingsTekst": string vertraging1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
                        case "EindBestemming": string eindbest1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
                        case "TreinSoort": string treinsoort1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
                        case "RouteTekst": string route1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;
                        case "VertrekSpoor": string spoor1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); i++ break;
                        case "Opmerkingen": case "Opmerking": string opmerking1 = (nodelist2.InnerText); break;

                    }


                }

            }
```

But it wasn't a success.
Is there a smarter way to read it, and place it in a lot of labels?

EDIT: 
With the answer I got, I tried the following code:

```
try
        {
            string urlo = "**secured webaddress that not end with .xml**";
            string resultje = HttpGeto(urlo);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;
            //* the document has one root element "ActueleVertrekTijden"
            //* the root element has multiple child nodes "VertrekkendeTrein" 
            XmlNodeList nodelist1 = root.ChildNodes;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodelist1.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlNodeList nodelist2 = nodelist1[i].ChildNodes;
                //* for each child node get all of all of child nodes,
                //* that is where you need to get the text within each one of them
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist2)
                {
                    switch (node.Name)
                    {
                        case "VertrekTijd":
                            string vertrek1 = node.InnerText; MessageBox.Show(vertrek1); lblts1.Text = vertrek1;
                            break;
                        case "VertrekVertragingsTekst":
                            string vertraging1 = node.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "EindBestemming":
                            string eindbest1 = node.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "TreinSoort":
                            string treinsoort1 = node.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "RouteTekst":
                            string route1 = node.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "VertrekSpoor":
                            string spoor1 = node.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "Opmerkingen":
                            XmlNode OpNode = node.FirstChild;
                            if (OpNode != null)
                            {
                                string opmerking1 = OpNode.InnerText;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch
        {
            lblcatch.Text = "werktniet";           
        }
```

But it doesn't work. And also, how can i read the next "VertrekkendeTrein"?, just by copying the code and use the I++;? I need to read the first 6 "VertrekkendeTrein".

Comment: have you done a google search on how to parse xml using C#.. there are tons of excellent working examples on the internet as well as here on `Stackoverflow.com`

Comment: what is nodeList, is it the nodeList from the root element of the XmlDocument, also you have a switch for nodelist.Name instead of nodelist2.Name

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if it works for you, it is based on all of the xml you are showing in your post

Comment: @faljbour, I changed my question, it doesn't work at the moment. I get no result.

Comment: @MethodMan I searched a lot on Google but didn't found what i need.

Comment: The way you wrote the code, it will never work.  XmlDocument has come from and xml file or and xml stream of some kind by using XmlReader.  your try, does not have a catch.  The for loop should give you all of  "VertrekkendeTrein" elements in the document, you do not need i++.  See my comments in the answer provided on how the code works.  I would recommend that you look at some xml documentation. Start with xml reader. Here is a link to it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx'

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;
//* the document has one root element "ActueleVertrekTijden"
//* the root element has multiple child nodes "VertrekkendeTrein" 
XmlNodeList nodelist1 = root.ChildNodes;
for (int i=0; i<nodelist1.Count; i++)
{
  XmlNodeList nodelist2 = nodelist1[i].ChildNodes;
  //* for each child node get all of all of child nodes,
  //* that is where you need to get the text within each one of them
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList2)
  {
    switch (node.Name)
    {
            case "VertrekTijd": 
  string vertrek1 = node.InnerText; 
  break;
  case "VertrekVertragingsTekst": 
  string vertraging1 = node.InnerText; 
  break;
  case "EindBestemming": 
  string eindbest1 = node.InnerText; 
  break;
  case "TreinSoort": 
  string treinsoort1 = node.InnerText; 
  break;
  case "RouteTekst": 
  string route1 = node.InnerText; 
  break;
  case "VertrekSpoor": 
  string spoor1 = node.InnerText; 
  break;
  case "Opmerkingen": 
  XmlNode OpNode = node.FirstChild;
  if(OpNode!=null)
  {
    string opmerking1 = OpNode.InnerText; 
  }
  break;
  }
  }
}
```